# Unity game levels do no load when building game on iphone

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, rtf, mobile-development

I am in the middle of creating a level based mobile game in unity and the levels are created using layout from a text file. So i read a text file and swap characters for certain prefabs, now the game works well when i run it in the unity editor but i recently decided to build and run it on my persona iPhone and everything is working as usual however the levels are not loading so the game is starting with out a level in it.

Why is this happening? this is an example of the game:
[example level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t744T.png)

the level is the platform that are under the cube which works in unity editor. but on device the level doesn't load and the cube just ends up falling endlessly

How do i fix this?

this is my LevelGenerator Script:

```
public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform [] platformPrefabs;
public Transform startingPlatformPrefab;
public Transform endingPlatformPrefab;
public Transform teleportPlatformPrefab;
public Transform shiftingPlatformPrefab;
public Transform movingPlatformPrefab;
public Transform buttonPlatformPrefab;

[SerializeField] Transform levelPosition;

public static LevelGenerator Instance { get; private set; }

private void Awake()
{
    if(Instance == null) { Instance = this; }
    else { Destroy(gameObject); }
}

public Transform GenerateLevel(int level)
{

    string levelFilePath = $"Assets/Levels/{level}.rtf";

    // Read the level RTF document
    string rtfContent = File.ReadAllText(levelFilePath);
    string plainTextContent = ReadRtfAsPlainText(rtfContent);

    string[] levelLines = plainTextContent.Split('\n');

    int width = levelLines[0].Length;
    int height = levelLines.Length;

    GameObject levelObject = new GameObject("Level");
    Transform levelTransform = levelObject.transform;

    bool useFirstPlatform = true;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            // Check if the current line has enough characters
            if (x >= levelLines[y].Length)
                break;

            char currentChar = levelLines[y][x];
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, Global.platformYPos, y);

            switch (currentChar)
            {
                case 'P':
                    // Spawn a platform prefab
                    Transform platformPrefab = useFirstPlatform ? platformPrefabs[0] : platformPrefabs[1];
                    PlaceBlock(platformPrefab, position, levelTransform, currentChar);
                    useFirstPlatform = !useFirstPlatform;
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    // Spawn a starting platform prefab
                    PlaceBlock(startingPlatformPrefab, position, levelTransform, currentChar);
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    // Spawn a button platform prefab
                    PlaceBlock(buttonPlatformPrefab, position, levelTransform, currentChar);
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    // Spawn a moving platform prefab
                    PlaceBlock(movingPlatformPrefab, position, levelTransform, currentChar);
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    // Set the target position for the moving platform
                    PlaceBlock(shiftingPlatformPrefab, position, levelTransform, currentChar);
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    // Spawn an ending platform prefab
                    PlaceBlock(endingPlatformPrefab, position, levelTransform, currentChar);
                    break;
                case 'K':
                    // Spawn an ending platform prefab
                    PlaceBlock(teleportPlatformPrefab, position, levelTransform, currentChar);
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    // Set the target position for the moving platform
                    movingPlatformPrefab.GetComponent<MovingPlatform>().targetPosition = position;
                    break;
                case 'W':
                    // Set the target position for the moving platform
                    shiftingPlatformPrefab.GetComponent<ShiftingPlatform>().pointB = new Vector3(position.x, 0, position.z);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    levelTransform.position = new Vector3(levelPosition.position.x, Global.levelParentYPos, levelPosition.position.z);
    
    return levelTransform;
}

private void PlaceBlock(Transform prefab, Vector3 position, Transform levelTransform, char currentChar)
{
    Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity, levelTransform);
}

string ReadRtfAsPlainText(string rtfContent)
{
    // Create a temporary text area to extract plain text from RTF
    TextEditor textEditor = new();
    textEditor.text = new GUIContent(rtfContent).ToString();
    textEditor.SelectAll();
    textEditor.Copy();

    return GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer;
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the text file.  Please include more information regarding the path and loading of the file.

Comment: You do know there is no "Assets" folder once its built right?

Comment: if this is the case where do i put the text file so that i can still generate my levels?

Comment: You can use a [TextAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html), though you need to change your text file from `rtf` to a supported file type.  For saving on the local device, use [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html).